# how to tap in content view in didselectrow method in tableview in swift

Tags: swift, tableview, cell, uitapgesturerecognizer

I am new in ios I am making a project using table view in which I have expanded the table view cell which has 4 Content view.When the table is loaded only first content view show and when I select the row then all content view expands. But I also want that after expanding the all content view cell when I tap on fourth content view then I want to access the indexPath.row in the tapGESTUREAction method of the fourth view.
    this my code of expanding Cell which consists of 4 content view
      func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
                  print(YearArr.count)
            return YearArr.count;
        }

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cellIdentifier = "Cell"
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier) as! customCell
        cell.selectionStyle = .none
             cell.lblGrossSal.text = EarnArr[indexPath.row]

         cell.lblTotlSal.text = netPayArr[indexPath.row]
         cell.lblmonthhName.text = YearArr[indexPath.row]
            print(selectedIndex,indexPath.row)
        let height = cell.bounds.height
        print(height)
       return cell;
    }

       func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        let cellIdentifier = "Cell"
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier) as! customCell
        cell.selectionStyle = .none

        if(selectedIndex == indexPath.row) {

                       return 190;
            return self.calculateHeight(selectedIndexPath: indexPath)
        } else {

                        return 50;
        }
           }
 // fourthView
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        if(selectedIndex == indexPath.row) {
            selectedIndex = -1
                   } else {
            selectedIndex = indexPath.row

        }
        self.expandTableView.beginUpdates()
        //self.expandTableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: UITableViewRowAnimation.automatic )
        self.expandTableView.endUpdates()


       }
    func calculateHeight(selectedIndexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        let cell = self.expandTableView.cellForRow(at: selectedIndexPath) as! customCell
        cell.lblDeductSal.frame = self.cellSummaryLabelFrame(cell: cell, selectedIndexPath: selectedIndexPath)

        return 80 + 35 + 21 + 10 + cell.lblDeductSal.frame.size.height + 30
    }

    func cellSummaryLabelFrame(cell: customCell, selectedIndexPath: IndexPath) -> CGRect {
        print(DeductionArr[selectedIndexPath.row])
        cell.lblDeductSal.text = DeductionArr[selectedIndexPath.row]
        cell.lblDeductSal.numberOfLines = 0
        var labelFrame = cell.lblDeductSal.frame
        let maxSize = CGSize.init(width: cell.lblDeductSal.frame.size.width, height: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude)
        let requiredSize = cell.lblDeductSal.sizeThatFits(maxSize)
        labelFrame.size.height = requiredSize.height
        return labelFrame
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In `heightForRowAt indexPath`, you are using two `return`. The first one will execute. The **calculated height** method can't execute. And there is no need of `tableView.dequeueReusableCell`. That function only need the height of cell.

Example:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    if(selectedIndex == indexPath.row) {
        return self.calculateHeight(selectedIndexPath: indexPath)
    } else {
        return 50;
    }
}
```

And You can also use dynamic cell height, In your **viewDidLoad**:

```
tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 44 //Default cell height
```

And here NO NEED OF `heightForRowAt indexPath` method. The height will automatically calculate.

Comment: Sir, its fine but my question is that how to get indexPath value of the row which is currently selected from didselectrow method to tapGesture method

Comment: how to tap the content view of cuurently selected row and get indexPath value

Comment: In `didSelectRowAt indexPath` delegate you will get current selected indexPath. If you want last selected indexPath, you will get it from `didDeSelectRowAt indexPath` delegate